# Informix SQL Syntax - AS Clause

Tags: informix

I am brand new to Informix and am having some problems with syntax.

Here is the query I am using against a MySQL DB:

```
select acceptable as "NUM",
       (callsoffered-outflowcalls-dequecalls-abncalls1-abncalls2-abncalls3-abncalls4) as "DEN"
from cms_hsplit 
WHERE 
row_date >= (current_date() - interval 9 day)
```

The table and column names are the same in the informix DB.  The above query fails in Informix.

What is the proper syntax for he "AS" portion?

and

What is the syntax to return the current day minus 9?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT acceptable AS num,
       callsoffered-outflowcalls-dequecalls-abncalls1-abncalls2-abncalls3-abncalls4 AS den
FROM cms_hsplit
WHERE row_date >= TODAY - 9
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  That syntax worked golden!

Comment: One last question...if using the AS I've found I cannot use two word with a space.

Comment: For example; SELECT acceptable AS num test,
       callsoffered-outflowcalls-dequecalls-abncalls1-abncalls2-abncalls3-abncalls4 AS den test  . This fails.  Can I use a single or double quote?

Comment: To get a 'multi-word' column alias, you must use `"num test"` but you also need `DELIMIDENT` set in the environment — see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Double quotes vs single quotes

Informix by default treats single quotes and double quotes identically as 'strings' (legacy behaviour from before the SQL-86 standard was a standard).  In standard SQL, single quotes are used for strings whereas double quotes surround 'delimited identifiers'.  Technically, what follows `AS` is not a string but an identifier.  Consequently, Informix does not allow the double quoted notation by default (a restriction that could, perhaps, be lifted with minimal confusion except to the SQL parser).

There are (at least) two ways around this:

1. Usually the best: do not use quotes around the name.
2. Set the environment variable `DELIMIDENT` so that double quoted 'strings' are treated as delimited identifiers rather than strings.  The value it is set to doesn't matter (even an empty string is sufficient), but I suggest `export DELIMIDENT=1` or `export DELIMIDENT=true` as sensible. Note that `export DELIMIDENT=0` or `export DELIMIDENT=false` has the same meaning as the other two.

Setting the environment variable means you have to be careful everywhere.  If you want spaces or other special characters in the alias names, you must use `DELIMIDENT` and double quotes.

Informix is more casual about quotes around 'user names' before table names and the like.

#### Date arithmetic

You can specify 'current day minus nine days' in several ways.  The two primary ones are:

```
WHERE row_date = TODAY - 9
WHERE row_date = CURRENT YEAR TO DAY - 9 UNITS DAY
```

The Informix `DATE` type is a count of the number of days since a reference date (1899-12-31 was day 0, so day 1 was 1900-01-01).  Consequently, you can add or subtract integers from a date value to get that many days after or before the date value.

The Informix `DATETIME` family of types is more complex, but very malleable.  Manipulation tends to be verbose — witness `CURRENT YEAR TO DAY` and `9 UNITS DAY`.  On the other hand, you can have a `DATETIME MONTH TO MINUTE` value if that suits your needs (or, more plausibly, `DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE`).